# How to render a 3d cube in LWJGL?

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl, cube

I can`t find a good tutorial on the web, about rendering a 3d cube in the Lightweight Java Game Library! I have been learning LWJGL for some  time now. I know how to draw 2d objects. Could Somebody Help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/3d_shapes/10035/) is a lesson of a tutorial for "normal" OpenGL but in the bottom of the site you can find code for the tutorial lesson in plenty of different languages and libraries, including Java with LWJGL.

To get the java code out of this jar you can open it with e.g. 7-zip and find the .java file in the folder named Lesson05.

Comment: There is also a whole bunch of tutorials on youtube about LWJGL3 and the first thing they do after setting up the window is rendering a square and a cube.